# _fpreset error in visual studio 2010

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

Good Morning.

I've got the following definition (this program was created by the guy who worked here before me) on a Visual Studio 2008 solution with c++:

```
[DllImport("msvcr70.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention::Cdecl)]
extern int _fpreset();
```

This line works perfect and I can call the _fpreset on the code.

Since we need to implement this as a 64 bits application I installed the Visual Studio 2010. Once we download the solution from the repository it ask me to do a conversion in order to work. I click yes and when I try to compile the program I get the following error:

```
error C2556:'int _fpreset(void)': overloaded functions only differ by return type with 'void _fpreset(void)'
```

When I try again in visual studio 2008 it works perfectly...

Any ideas why it doesn't work on 2010?

Comment: It sounds like _fpreset() is declared more than once.

Comment: yeah, but if I remove that declaration, when I use it I get the following warning: `'_fpreset': Direct floating point control is not supported or reliable from within managed code`

Comment: Well, yes.  [The documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kfy34skx.aspx) says "the common language runtime only supports the default floating-point precision."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The declaration is just wrong.  You are now being reminded about it because some other VS2010 .h file you #include pulls in float.h, the header file that declares _fpreset().  Which gives the proper declaration of this CRT function with a return type of *void*.

You should delete this [DllImport] declaration, not just because it is wrong but it also gives your program a dependency on the ancient VS2002 CRT (msvcr70.dll).  Add this to whatever source code file that actually calls _fpreset():

```
 #include <float.h>
```

Calling _fpreset() in managed code is pretty iffy, only do so when you are calling native code that messes up the FPU control word.